# How can I show the most recent events per user with Keen IO?

Tags: keen-io

Suppose you have a Keen IO collection called "survey-completed" that contains events matching the following pattern:

```
keen.id: <unique autogenerated id>
keen.timestamp: <autogenerated overridable timestamp>
userId: <hex string for user>
surveyScore: <integer from 1 to 10>
...
```

How would you create a report of *only* the most up-to-date satisfaction score for each user that responded to one or more surveys within a given amount of time (such as one week)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a really elegant way to make it happen, but for a given `userId` you could successfully return your the most up-to-date event create a `count` query with a [`group_by`](https://keen.io/docs/api/#group-by) on [surveyScore, keen.timestamp] and an [`order_by`](https://keen.io/docs/api/#order-by) on the `keen.timestamp` property. You will want to set [`limit`](https://keen.io/docs/api/#limiting-the-number-of-groups-returned)=1 to select only the most recent `surveyScore`.

If you'd like to use an [extraction](https://keen.io/docs/api/#extractions), the most straight forward way would be to run an extraction with `property_names` set to `["userId","keen.timestamp","surveyScore"]`. Once you receive the results you can then do some client-side post processing. This is probably the best way if you want to take a look at all of your `userId`s.

If you're interested in a given `userId` and want to use an `extraction`, you can run an extraction with a filter on the `userId eq X`, define the optional parameter `latest` set to `latest=1`. The `latest` property is an integer containing the number of most recent events to extract. Note: The use of `latest` will call upon the `keen.created_at` timestamp instead of `keen.timestamp` (https://keen.io/docs/api/#the-keen-object).